# REST API - Securing with OAuth 2.0

Tags: api, rest, symfony

I'm practicing my Symfony 2 skills and would like to set up a simple REST API for a tiny application of mine.

I've set up REST Api with FOSRestBundle in few minutes. Perfectly. After setting it up, I've decided to secure it with OAuth. I've decided to go with FOSOAuthServerBundle. The stuff is working perfectly.

I've readed tons of materials and I'm wondering if I understand all of the stuff correctly. I understand how OAuth works, I'm just not sure if it was a good choice for my problem.

In fact, there will be many consumers available: users will be able to create their own apps based on the data fetched from API, there might be CMS plugin.

I suppose I misunderstood OAuth protocol in few ways: does OAuth always require end user action (giving a client app a permission)? Does users always have to re-authorize an app after access_token has expired?

Let's say an user want to fetch his content within my API - just to fetch some non-sensitive data. Does it require authorizing an app by the end user? I think I'm a bit lost here.

To avoid questions, yes I've read [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) few times and reading it all the time ;) I just think it's better to ask instead of copying terrible solutions, practices and false knowledge.